# Why does code compile when you attempt to access a value in 0 as an array?

Tags: arrays, c, operators, postfix-operator

Let's say you have the code as follows:

```
float arr[] = {
    0.0f,
    1.0f,
    62.0f,
    400.0f
};
```

Then I print this out as follows:

```
printf("%lu\n", sizeof(0[arr]));
```

Why does it return 4, and what is happening here?

Comment: `x[i]` is a syntactic sugar for `*(x+i)`, which is the same as `*(i+x)` which is in turn `i[x]`. There are should be a bunch of duplicates for this...

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Would you expect a beginning student to know what “X is syntactic sugar for Y” means? That’s not a defined term. Is there something in colloquial language you think they would relate it to? Would it have any more meaning for them than if you said “X is parsing maple syrup for Y?”

Comment: Note that the correct `printf` directive for a `size_t` argument (such as the result of the `sizeof` operator) is `%zu`.  The `%lu` appearing in the example code may happen to be equivalent on some platforms, but it is quite wrong on others.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I come from java development, where to my knowledge, something like this doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the C Standard (6.5.2.1 Array subscripting)

> 2 A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets []
> is a subscripted designation of an element of an array object. The
> definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to
> (*((E1)+(E2))). Because of the conversion rules that apply to the
> binary + operator, if E1 is an array object (equivalently, a pointer
> to the initial element of an array object) and E2 is an integer,
> E1[E2] designates the E2-th element of E1 (counting from zero).

So this expression `0[arr]` is equivalent to the expression `arr[0]`.

The only difference is relative to how the subscript operator is defined in the C grammar.

It is defined like

```
postfix-expression [ expression ]
```

So for example

`++i[arr]` is not the same as `arr[++i]`. The first expression is equivalent to `++( i[arr] )`. While this expression `i++[arr]` is equivalent to `arr[i++]`.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int arr[] = { 10, 20 };
    size_t i = 0;

    printf( "++i[arr] = %d\n", ++i[arr] );

    i = 0;

    printf( "arr[++i] = %d\n", arr[++i] );
    
    putchar( '\n' );

    i = 0;
    arr[0] = 10;

    printf( "i++[arr] = %d\n", i++[arr] );

    i = 0;

    printf( "arr[i++] = %d\n", arr[i++] );
}
```

The program output is

```
++i[arr] = 11
arr[++i] = 20

i++[arr] = 10
arr[i++] = 10
```